# how to know needed cache size?

Tags: magento-1.7, cache, cache-improvement

How do I know how much cache I should have?
I am always increasing the ram disk for var folder. Now it is 2GB.
Looks like Magento could eat all cache space.
Whenever I run a api script, I have to clear cache before to speed this operations up.
How do I know, what kind of stuff uses how much space in the cache?

Comment: 40000 products, 25 store views, each product with around 2500 signs description